# Generate MD5SUM to compare table to itself

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare a table to itself before, after the change and after we rollback the change 
I'm thinking on using MD5SUM for this, but i'm not sure that oracle 11g can do it

How can I make an MD5SUM of entire table ?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing a difference of the table data.  You can use linked tables to accomplish this.  If you get any records from the query, there are differences.  In my example, TABLEA is local, the OTHERDBLINK is a link to the other database where TABLEA also resides.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TABLEA
MINUS
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TABLEA@OTHERDBLINK
UNION
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TABLEA@OTHERDBLINK
MINUS
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: in this case I need to store a copy of my original table somewhere and then do my changes; that's works too but I thought that md5checksum would be easier ...